# Inserting value in a csv from another csv based on matching values of in one field

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files. csv-1 has ID, NAME, and other columns, the ID field however, has no values in it. CSV 2 also has ID and NAME columns, and both are populated. Now, I want to insert the ID values in csv-1 from csv-2 where values of the NAME in both files are the same. I need to do it by python (with or without pandas). Any lead will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Some information is missing, like

- are the sizes (rows) of both csv the same or different. neverthless, you need a set-up like this
- Assuming sizes are same...

```py
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv(<csv1 location>)
df2=pd.read_csv(<csv2 location>)
df1['ID'] = df2['ID'].values
df1.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```